# Vbulletin Users integration with a .NET site

Tags: asp.net, vbulletin

Does anyone know how to integrate the vbulletin forums users with an existing .net site that it has its own users and login, and to maintain the session between the two sites, so when a user logs in, he stays logged in when browsing the forum?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've implemented user integration between disparate systems sharing a cookie with some encrypted information that each system take care to decode and auto-login the user if they match.

You have to put each system in the same domain to be able to share the cookie.